# [linphone-sdk ios]Getting Error No such module 'linphonesw'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, linphone, linphone-sdk

We are using compiled linphone sdk.Integrate compiled sdk in our project but getting below error "No such module 'linphonesw'.
linphonesw folder created but how to add in our project.
we are using linphone-sdk 4.4.2 and linphone-iPhone project 4.2.2.
please help us to resolve this error.
PFA.
Thank you.
[[image]]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Make you pod file correctly and try `pod install`
- Otherwise if you want to use locally then try.

  ```
  PODFILE_PATH=<path to linphone-sdk-ios> pod install
  ```

or if you make it via compiled sdk

```
$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk.git
```

Comment: i tried to add compiled sdk not used linphone pod.so any idea related to using compiled SDK then please share.

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue,any new solution?

I installed linphone sdk osx using Pods With the following command in the Pod file

pod 'linphone-sdk', '5.0.69', :source => ‘https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/podspec-macos.git'
After executing command pod install and installing successfully Gives this error for import linphonesw

No such module 'linphonesw'
[image]